# podfile for Google-Maps-iOS-SDK

Tags: cocoapods, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm doing an app with AFNetworking and Google Maps.

I don't see any helpfile on this. This is the first time I'm going to use cocoapods so I think I need help. Will this podfile work?

```
platform :ios, '7.1'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'
pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-SDK', '~> 1.7.2'
```

Comment: I was not able to find the right pod name for the Google Maps iOS SDK, and I came across your answer which provided me the right pod name. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Yes this will work. In fact, I'm using an almost identical podfile for a current project I'm working on. Just run

```
pod install
```

in the root directory of your project and you should be good. Might I ask what made you think it wouldn't work? Did you try it yourself?

Comment: I ran pod install the second time and the files were downloaded. Somehow it wasn't downloaded with the other pods the first time.